# How to get and filter all referenced FAL files with extbase

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I'm working on an extension, which displays all files referenced in **sys_file_reference**.
There is also the possibility to categorize and filter every file based on a new custom property in **sys_file_metadata**.

What's the best way to get and filter all referenced files as `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File` model?

With the help of `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileRepository` i was able to get the `File` models including the metadata. 
But the repository expects always a `uid` to retrieve a `File`. By now i fetch all referenced files with my repository and pass them to the `findFileReferenceByUid()` method.

```
class DocumentRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository {

    /**
     * Disables pid constraint
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function initializeObject() {
        $querySettings = $this->objectManager->create('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Typo3QuerySettings');
        $querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
        $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
    }

    /**
     * Finds all referenced documents returning them as File modules
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function findAllReferenced() {
        $fileRepository = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Resource\\FileRepository');
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        $documents = $query->execute();
        $references = array();

        foreach ($documents as $document) {
            $references[] = $fileRepository->findFileReferenceByUid($document->getUid());
        }

        return $references;
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler way and how could i implement the filter?

**Update**

For now i bypass extbase and use the database connection directly. TYPO3 does this internally a lot.

```
/**
 * Finds all referenced documents returning them as File models
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function findAllReferenced() {

    $rows = $this->getDatabaseConnection()->exec_SELECTgetRows(
        'sys_file AS sf
            LEFT JOIN tt_content AS ttc ON ttc.header_link=CONCAT("file:", sf.uid)
            LEFT JOIN sys_file_reference AS ref ON sf.uid=ref.uid_local
            LEFT JOIN sys_file_metadata AS meta ON sf.uid=meta.file',
        '((ttc.uid IS NOT NULL AND ttc.hidden = 0 AND ttc.deleted = 0) OR (ref.uid IS NOT NULL AND ref.hidden = 0 AND ref.deleted = 0))',
        'sf.uid'
    );

    $documents = array();

    if (!empty($rows)) {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $documents[] = $this->createDomainObject($row);
        }
    }
    return $documents;
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem? I'm looking for the same, to get all file objects which are referenced in typo3. Hope you could help me please.

Comment: I updated my question. Hope it helps :)